# Normal Subgroups of Parabolic Groups in Simple Lie Groups

Tags: lie-groups

If G is a noncompact simple (real) Lie group with trivial center and Q is a parabolic subgroup of G, is there a "nice" description of the normal subgroups of Q?

In particular, is there any "nice" condition on G that will ensure that Q is simple?